# Does commerce send an order notification email to site admin (site email) out of the box?

Tags: 7, commerce

Does commerce send an order notification email to site admin (site email) out of the box?

If not how do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like it does, no. There is, however, a rule set up to send the order notification to the user. It's called "Send an order notification e-mail".

You can easily clone this rule, but instead of sending the email to the owner of the order, send it to the admin's email address.

The admin user isn't available as a data selector for this rule, so you'll either have to expose it yourself somehow (not sure exactly how you'd do that without custom coding off the top of my head), or simply switch to 'direct input mode' and put the email address in manually.

Comment: Perfect. site:mail was an available data selector.

Comment: Sweet, forgot about that one :)

Comment: site:mail is not available for me :-(

Comment: @mb14 It definitely should be, that's one of the most basic tokens available through the data selector. It's a global token so should be there for every single rule

Comment: @clive: I might be missing something but the data selector (User for new entity : message) only displays site:current-user or commerce...user. If I enter manually site:mail I got an invalid value error

Comment: Sorry I should have qualified that - it's there for every single data selector that's looking for an email address. The rule you're describing is looking for an account object (from which the system will retrieve the email address automatically). If you have the opportunity to enter an email address manually anywhere in a rules data selector you should be getting the `[site:mail]` token

Comment: Which rule should I use then ? The rule you are describing expect a user not an email. I tried to modify it but a message is expecting a user too. I can't find a way to set the email of a message.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure, it's always just worked for me (and for the asker of this question evidently). Make sure you have the latest version of rules and required modules etc

Comment: I'm using commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.0-rc4. Which version should I use and which rules ?

Comment: I'm not a developer for Drupal Commerce or anything like that, I wouldn't know. Their website is [here](http://drupalcommerce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include line items in the email to site admin, I'd recommend using https://drupal.org/project/commerce_email

Although the project page doesn't mention it, there are also dependencies on these modules:
variable
variable_email
htmlmail

Answer (score -1):

You could "Clone" It's called "Send an order notification e-mail" and edit Data selector to site:mail (or switch to the direct mode to fill your e-mail address).